# [GIT]Deleted file from My_Branch under GIT is showing back in the eclipse My_Branch workspace when REFRESH

Tags: git, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOFHr.png)

1. I used Git rm file_name.txt
2. I tried manually deleting the file
3. For both the ways mentioned in 1. and 2. file is shown as deleted in the git status cmd result.
4. But, when checking in the eclipse My_Branch(saisree/cpi) workspace, it's still showing back the deleted file after refresh

Attached the screenshot. Please help

Thanks,
Saisree

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? You used git to remove the file, but never committed the deletion so it will come back after stashing.

Comment: @sai3_forever After deleting file, did you committed and pushed the file?

Comment: There are differen kinds of _refresh_ in Eclipse. In your case (when doing some Git operation outside of Eclipse), you have to hit the refresh button either in the _Git Repositories_ or _Git Staging_ view (a refresh in the _Project/Package Explorere_ is to sync with the file system, not with Git).